# Intermediate page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I want to use both regular page numbering (as in 1, 2, 3, etc) and n-m page numbering (1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2, etc) in a document I'm preparing.

This far I've been playing around with custom counters but the obvious answer, using `\addtocounter` to subtract the page where the current chapter started from `\thepage` defeats that purpose because I still want regular page numbers.

I can't really post an MWE because it's something I don't really know how to do. On the "pseudo-MWE" below `\nmpage` is a hypothetic command that outputs the page number in the format `<chapter>-<page_of_chapter>`, so the 5th page of chapter 2 would be 2-5.

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
  \pagestyle{fancy}  
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%  
    \markboth{#1}{}}  
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%  
    \markright{\thesection #1}}  
  \fancyhf{}  
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}%   
  \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}%  
  \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}%  
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\nmpage}%  

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

Onononononon

\chapter{Chapter 2}

Yada yada yada.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which is the main page number, especially which is used for references (`\pageref`)?

Comment: It's `\thepage`, which I intentionally leave untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main page number is `\thepage` with regular (arabic) numbering. This is also used for page references. Thus we do not need to do anything here.

Additionally the footer should show a page number of the form `\thechapter-<arabic page relative to the chapter>`. All we need is the page number of the chapter start. Since `\chaptermark` is already redefined, the definition for `\StartChapterPage` is put there.
A chapter starts a new page, thus we can use `\value{page}` without resorting to the referencing system. Second advantage of `\chaptermark` is that it is not called for unnumbered chapters. In order to skip the first pages, `\nmpage` is defined empty and `\printnmpage` is defined to do the real work. At the first numbered chapter `\nmpage` gets the meaning of `\printnmpage` and the composite page number is shown:

The following definitions are added to the MWE of the question:

```
\newcommand*{\StartChapterPage}{1}
\newcommand*{\nmpage}{}
\newcommand*{\printnmpage}{%
  \thechapter-\the\numexpr\value{page}-\StartChapterPage+1\relax
}
```

And the definition for `\chaptermark` changes as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \xdef\StartChapterPage{\the\value{page}}%
  \global\let\nmpage\printnmpage
  \markboth{#1}{}}
```

Comment: Wow. Just... wow. I may have learned more about LaTeX in the past minute than in the last week. Thank you, Heiko.

Answer (score 3):

That can be achieved by creating a new counter that is reset with each chapter, then incrementing it everytime it is used in the headings:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{nmpage}[chapter]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thechapter--\addtocounter{nmpage}{1}\thenmpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The beginning}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-6]


\chapter{More Material}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

Maybe looking at the `memoir` class might be a better place.  I was using the `book` class.

Comment: The `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` trick is described in the manual of `fancyhdr`

Comment: My problem is not with fancyhdr - what I need is the page number in the footer to be reset everytime a new chapter begins, to the first page of chapter 2 would be 2-1, not 2-3.

Comment: You could order the page counter to reset. But I wouldn't touch it and rather create a new counter which is reseted every chapter. I don't remember how to do it at this moment, but if no one answers I will look around.

Comment: `\newcounter{nmpage}[chapter]` would do just that. The catch is how to increment it every time `page` is incremented.

Comment: In the code of @A.Ellet instead of `\cfoot{\thechapter--\thepage}` you should use `\cfoot{\thechapter--\addtocounter{nmpage}{1}\thenmpage}`. I think it works. But you should redefine some more commands if you want `\pageref` and similar to work. I hope someone answers.